# Use secondary IP as outgoing IP on SOCKS5 traffic that uses this IP

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, socks

I have a server that runs OpenVPN on it's primary IP.

There is also a second IP I connect to using SSH as a SOCKS5 setup like this:

`ssh -C2qTnN -D 1337 me@<secondary-ip>`

I go to whatismyip.com from each connection and I want to see the primary IP when I connect through the VPN and the secondary when I connect through the SOCKS5 proxy (assuming my browser is using the proxy obviously) but now always the primary IP shows.

What trickery do I need to do to fix this?

Edit: this is on a vps and the different IP addresses are on interfaces venet0:0 and venet0:1

Comment: This may be helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/750473/tunnelling-through-an-ip-alias/750478

Comment: @parkamark thank you but I don't see how?